# Infinite loading package in apt-get, infinite Get

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, apt

Ubuntu 16.04.3 xenial

`apt-get update` is not working - infinity Get. Apt endlessly tries to download a package:

```
...
Get:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]
Get:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]
Get:10 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons [7,448 kB]
...
```

I changed the addresses of the mirrors in the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` but it did not help.

The problem is not this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/774918/apt-get-is-stuck-at-fetched-xxkb-in-xxsec

What's going on?

Comment: See if this is related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/775049/16-04-apt-update-never-ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/964096/746294

> If you are using any (transparent) proxy severs, it may be a
>   misconfiguration of a proxy. Try to use HTTPS mirrors to eliminate
>   such issues.

How to verify that packets are cut:

```
curl http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/universe/binary-i386/by-hash/SHA256/504313460a80c8d83fe8a45d2958284e5255ba0776b3e729074c8f8a7368d191 > /dev/null
```

The result of running `curl`, which says *that packages are not downloaded*:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 7335k    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (18) transfer closed with 7512036 bytes remaining to read
```

It is necessary to configure the proxy server.

Quick solution: replace in `/etc/apt/sources.list` **HTTP** mirrors with **HTTPS** mirrors. For example, `http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com` replace with `https://mirror.yandex.ru`

Answer (score 0):

The default version for PHP in Ubuntu packages is 7 right now and there is no need to mention the version in your installation `php7.0`.

Try to purge everything about php7 and then install php without mentioning the version.

Delete everything using these commands (use `sudo`):

```
apt-get remove php7.0-*
apt-get --purge remove php7.0
apt-get --autoremove
apt-get --autoclean
```

Make sure that there is nothing related to php7.0 in your php folder:

```
ls /etc/php
```

Then just install php without mentioning the version, it will install the last version of php7 (use `sudo`):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php
```

*P.S: There is no need to mention the version for installing the extensions as well. Just install them like this (use `sudo`):*

```
apt-get install php-json
```

*P.S: If this didn't work, try changing Ubuntu repository mirrors to another country's CDN like this and try again (use `sudo`):*

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

*Then change all of the `ru` to another country like `de`.*

*Then save the file and try again.*